# How did Chadwick determine the speed of protons?

Tags: experimental-physics, history, neutrons

Chadwick, or perhaps one of the previous scientists who were working with the neutron experiment were able to determine the velocity of the protons ejected from the Paraffin wax.

[image]

I thought that the ionisation chamber would only able to detect how many ionisations were occurring per second not what the velocity of the protons were. I guess if the protons had a faster velocity then it would probably produce more ionisations, but how could they quantify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [discovery paper](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1932.0112), Chadwick writes that he measured the stopping power of the protons by adding layers of aluminum foil between the paraffin and the ion chamber and watching the proton count decrease. He then looked up this stopping power on a reference curve relating a proton's range in matter to its velocity. (A modern paper would have a more obvious citation for this reference data.)

In a modern ion chamber you can get lots of information, including sometimes transit time information, by connecting the chamber to an oscilloscope.  But Chadwick's language makes me think that his oscillograph (this was before oscilloscopes) gave him information about the total ionization for an event, but not detailed timing information that he could have used to directly measure the proton's speed.  His reference data would have been easy to produce using a cyclotron, where a proton beam's energy and speed can be controlled fairly precisely.

Comment: That was very insightful - but this only kind of pushes on the quesiton - how did those people who made the refernece chart know the velocity of their protons?

Comment: If I were in 1930 and had just invented the cyclotron, the first thing I might do would be to generate protons with known speed and measure their stopping power. Chadwick's lack of any reference suggests these data were not new or controversial, however. A good place for questions like "what physics data was widely available in 1930?" is [hsm.se].